# Why is "like IRadio" required for radioIn connection to stop gate is not connected to sibling error?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have created a simple node that passes things to the network layer `BroadcastRouting` which then just forwards them back again.

I was getting the error: `Gate 'radioIn' is not connected to sibling or parent module.` 
I fixed it with giving the input gate  the property `@directIn` and by making the Physical layer `<default("Ieee802154UwbIrRadio")> like IRadio` instead of just `Ieee802154UwbIrRadio`

Why did this fix it?
I thought that the Ieee802154UwbIrRadio already had the radioIn gate.

```java
module Node
{
    @display("bgl=8;bgb=97,315");
    gates:
        input radioIn @directIn;
    submodules:
        Physical: <default("Ieee802154UwbIrRadio")> like IRadio {
            @display("p=41,74");
        }
        Link: Ieee802154Mac {
            @display("p=41,169");
        }
        Net: BroadcastRouting {
            @display("p=41,248");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        radioIn --> Physical.radioIn;
        Physical.upperLayerOut --> Link.lowerLayerIn;
        Physical.upperLayerIn <-- Link.lowerLayerOut;
        Link.upperLayerOut --> Net.fromMac;
        Link.upperLayerIn <-- Net.toMac;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the encapsulation concept working, INET's radio infrastructure (more precisely the module that manages the medium itself) expects that your `Node` module has a `radioIn` gate. The wireless messages will be delivered to that gate using `directSend()` calls. Now because these gates are **not** connected to anything on the outside, while they are obviously connected to the `Physical` module's gate OMNeT++ throws an error as this is a typical error. That's why you explicitly have to tag the gate with `@directIn` annotation, to disable this validation check.

The fact, that that gate is connected (on the inside) to the `Physical.radioIn` gate or that the `Ieee802154UwbIrRadio` has a `radioIn` gate is just an implementation detail. It should *not* matter, as it is inside the node.